# Create own laravel package

Tags: laravel

I try to create own laravel package.
I created **package** folder in my project in root directory.

Than created **simplexi/greetr/src** folders in **package**.

I added to autoload **"Simplexi\Greetr\": "package/simplexi/greetr/src"** in composer.json in main project, and used command composer dump-autoload.

Than in src folder I created RiakServiceProvider, added this provider to **config=>app.php** to providers array.

Then in boot method I added next code:

`$this->publishes([__DIR__ . '../config/myconf.php' => config_path() . '/']);`

And executed next command:

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="\Simplexi\Greetr\RiakServiceProvider"`

Than I got **Publishing complete.**
But file myconf.php didn't copy to app/config.
Also I checked file myconf.php in my **package/simplexi/greetr/config** folder and it exists.

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: what is your laravel version?

Comment: @Hossien 5.6 version

Comment: I guess you should set the second parameter too: `$this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '../config/myconf.php' => config_path() . '/'
    ], 'config');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`publishes()` expect two parameters. Try something like this:

```
$this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../config/myconf.php' => config_path('myconf.php'),
    ], 'config');
```

Comment: Thank you, This code worked for me, but one little point. I removed **myconf.php** from **__DIR__.'/../config/myconf.php'** and all work good